# Ruby on Rails - encoding issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding

I am running a RoR app that pulls data from some event tables which are using utf8_general_ci as collation.

The problem is that all my pages render stuff like this:

Atat�rk Stadi Nov 02 20:00

So far I have tried:
- changing the encoding within application.rb

- adding

  ```
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  ```
- adding

  ```
  content="text/html;charset=utf-8"
  ```
- all combinations of above tags with all possible relevant encodings that may apply to our content.

Document type is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I have also tried HTML5 and other variations.

I have not yet tried the iconv solution, would prefer not having to go down that road.

Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this?

Thank you!
N.

Comment: what versions of Ruby and Rails are you using?

Comment: I have two apps on the same DB, one is using 2.2.2 and one is using 3.2.1, both have the same problem.

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02

Comment: do you have a `encoding: utf8` in your `config/database.yml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have a encoding: utf8 in your config/database.yml file?